# Having a CSS menu aligned properly

Tags: html, css

I'm working on simple website with a menu bar that's pinned at the top of the page as you scroll down, that part is working properly.

I have two div tags, one floated to the left with text logo and another div tag floated to the right with a ul menu.

The website's main content is in a 960 x [variable height] content area.

I would always like my logo floated to the left to be left aligned to the left edge of the content area and the right end of my menu to always be aligned to the right end of my content area. So that if the website is larger than 960px the logo is always at 0px and the end of the ul list with padding ends at 960px.

My Logo styling

```
Heading container:
position: relative;
background-color: white;
height: 120px;
margin: 0px auto;
border-bottom: solid 2px #ffc900;

position:fixed;
z-index: 1;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0;

Logo Container H1:
float: left;
font-size: 48px;
color: #ffc900;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 15px 0px 0px 120px;
font-weight: normal;

Heading container H5:
clear: both;
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: #0070ff;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 124px;
font-weight: normal;
```

Here is my list styling:

```
Main_Nav:
float: right;
display: block;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
color: #0070ff;
padding: 7px 20px 10px 20px;
margin: -4px 4px 0px 0px;
left: -65px;    


Main_Nav a, .Main_Nav li:
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
display: block;
color: #0070ff;
margin: -5px 3px 0px 0px;
left: 170px;


Main_Nav a 
padding: 7px 15px 10px 15px;
```

Comment: Seems like you're forgetting to use `#` for styling elements with `id` and `.` for styling elements with `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your logo like this. Your menu seems to look fine.

```
#Logo {
position: absolute; //add this
left: 0;  //add this
top: 0;  //add this
float: left; // remove this line
font-size: 48px;
color: #ffc900;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 15px 0px 0px 120px;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me sort things out!